# How to redirect specific post type with user role

Tags: user-roles, dashboard, user-access

I have created custom post type `Books` in my `functions.php`. Now I want to redirect every user (assigned with `editor` role). When they click to Dashboard it goes to this page:

```
http://www.localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=product
```

What I want:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
add_action('load-index.php', 'redirect_dashboard');

function redirect_dashboard() {
  if ( ! is_admin() || current_user_can('activate_plugins') ) return;
  $screen = get_current_screen();
  if ( is_object($screen) && $screen->base == 'dashboard' ) {
    $url = admin_url('edit.php');
    wp_safe_redirect( add_query_arg( array('post_type' => 'product'), $url) );
    die();
  }
}
```

Comment: It is also affecting to main administrator page. I want only editor role otherwise you code is perfect for me. Can you help me how to fix that also.

Comment: @Manan I've edited the code. Just a little addition on first `if`. In the question you said _"i want to redirect every user"_ not _"i want to redirect every editor"_ or I would use this code on first publish.